# How would I cut out part of what a camera renders in Unity, to show another camera's render behind it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

[image: If you printed two images, cut out a circle, and placed another behind it, that is what you would see here. It would let you see through the circle to the image behind.]
The above image is what I am trying to replicate in Unity using the default renderer. I need a mesh or plane or anything to cut out part of what the camera renders, and show what the other camera renders instead.

I tried using a Render Texture and culling masks, neither of which worked. I did look at shaders, but I never used them before, which is why I need help. If someone understands shaders, or knows a better solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

This question is probably a little short, but my longer draft was deleted and I don't want to go over every detail again. Also, I am using the default renderer and this will be a VR application, which I thought I should mention incase that completely changes what I have to do. It's not to late to change renderer if needed though.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without writing shader, you can just use a UI mask to show the RenderTexture. I suppose you have 2 layers L and M, a RenderTexture R, here is the hierachy:

```
Camera1 (culling mask = L)
Camera2 (culling mask = M, target = R)
Object1 (layer = L)
Object2 (layer = M)
Canvas
  Mask (Mask and Image components)
    Image (Raw Image component, texture = R)
```

Set the target of the Camera2 to the RenderTexture, then create a UI canvas, add a Mask and a RawImage underneath it, give a sprite to the Mask, set the texture of the RawImage to the RenderTexture, now you should see the RenderTexture is masked.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution for most projects, but I am trying to make this work in VR, and I don't believe overlay canvases draw in virtual reality.

Comment: Screen Space Camera renderer mode should work, use Camera1 to render the texture and the scene, you can have a try.